# Python and selenium to login to website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use Selenium within Python to login to a website and then download some freely available information once per day to monitor how it changes over time.

The website has registration and login next to each other, and both use the same id

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.acquirersmultiple.com/login/')

#login_user = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.rcp_login_data > p:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(2)')
username = browser.find_element_by_id("rcp_user_login")
password = browser.find_element_by_id('rcp_user_pass')

username.send_keys("SomeUser")
password.send_keys("P4s5word")
```

Results in SomeUser as username on the website in the registration field, not the login.

I tried selecting by css selector, no luck there either.

Answer (score 2):

The login fields are under the login form. You can locate the form and use it to locate the fields

```
login_form = browser.find_element_by_id('rcp_login_form')
username = login_form.find_element_by_id('rcp_user_login')
password = login_form.find_element_by_id('rcp_user_pass')
```

Or use it in the locator

```
username = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#rcp_login_form #rcp_user_login')
password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#rcp_login_form #rcp_user_pass')
```

Comment: Your answer solves the problem but you don't explain why. The main problem is that the ID that OP is using is not unique on the page and the first element found matching that ID is under Register New Account.

Comment: @JeffC The OP already metioned it in the post. I didn't think there is any point posting it again.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, when I don't find unique element using id or name. 
Go to it's parent folder and check if that's uniquely identifiable if not go to it's parent until you find the element. And then form an xpath.

For you the xpath for usename and passwod will look like this.

```
//form[@id='rcp_login_form']//*[@name='rcp_user_login']
//form[@id='rcp_login_form']//*[@name='rcp_user_pass']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You have used the locator `id` to locate the elements `Username` and `Password` fields from the `Subscriber Login` section, but those locators are not unique across the HTML DOM. We need to construct unique `xpath` which can identify the elements. You can use the following code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
browser.get('http://www.acquirersmultiple.com/login/')
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 400);")
username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='rcp_login_form']//input[@id='rcp_user_login']")
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='rcp_login_form']//input[@id='rcp_user_pass']")
username.send_keys("SomeUser")
password.send_keys("P4s5word")
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Selector solution:

```
username = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("form#rcp_login_form input#rcp_user_login")
password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('form#rcp_login_form input#rcp_user_pass')
```